# equals on objects that contain different types of collections

Tags: java, collections

I have an object that looks like this (I've using a bit of the Guava library in order to simply my equals and hashcode methods):

```
public class MyClass {
    private Collection<Integer> integers;
    private Collection<String> strings;

    // Getters and Setters...

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object o) {
        if (o == this) {
            return true;
        }
        if (o == null || getClass() != o.getClass()) {
            return false;
        }

        MyClass that = (MyClass) o;

        return Objects.equal(integers, that.integers) &&
               Objects.equal(strings, that.strings);
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        return Objects.hashCode(integers, strings);
    }
}
```

The issue I'm running into is with code that essentially does this (this would be a typical test case):

```
// Produce a new instance of MyClass that users ArrayLists.
MyClass expected = new MyClass();
expected.setIntegers(Arrays.asList(1, 2, 3));
expected.setStrings(Arrays.asList("a", "b"));

// I don't normally construct the actual object here, 
// but I've included the code so you get an understanding of what's happening

// Produce a new instance of MyClass that uses HashSets.
Set<Integer> someNumbers = new HashSet<Integer>();
someNumbers.add(1);
someNumbers.add(2);
someNumbers.add(3);
Set<String> someStrings = new HashSet<String>();
someStrings.add("a");
someStrings.add("b");
MyClass actual = new MyClass();
actual.setIntegers(someNumbers);
actual.setIntegers(someStrings);

assertEquals(expected, actual);
```

The problem I'm running into is that even though the contents of the collections are all the same and the compile-time type of those members is "Collection", the run-time types are used to evaluate equality so this assertion fails. Looking at the source code for AbstractSet.equals and AbstractList.equals, they check to see if the other object is a Set or a List, respectively, before they evaluate the contents.

I suppose that makes some sense because order matters in a list and doesn't in a set, so, even if the contents are the same, you can't compare them.

That said, in this case, I don't care what the underlying collection is - I just want to know if the contents are the same and order makes no difference. Is there any easy way to do this?

Comment: You could copy the contents of one collection into a `Set<OtherClass>` and compare if all the elements of the other collection are present in the `Set`.

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza It shouldn't be a set, it will regard two lists [1,2] and [1,1,2] as equal.

Comment: @amit this would depend on OP's requirement to say one collection is equals to another.

Answer (score 1):

In the case the underlying collection does not matter to you, you could switch to one pre-defined ordered collection that allows repeats, make sure the two new collections are sorted, and then check for equality.

One simple way to do it is convert your elements to arrays using [`toArray()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Collection.html#toArray%28T%5B%5D%29), sort it with [`Arrays.sort()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#sort%28java.lang.Object%5B%5D%29), and check for equality using [`Arrays.equals()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#equals%28java.lang.Object%5B%5D,%20java.lang.Object%5B%5D%29)

Answer (score 0):

Just do not do it! There's no possible sane re-definition of `equals` for `Collection` as its subclasses `List` and `Set` define it in an incompatible way. So the only possibility is to stick with existing `equals` inherited from `Object`, i.e., testing reference equality.

---

Actually, there's a solution for your problem... although it's more of another problem than a solution. If you want to consider `integers` equals whenever they're equals as `List` (or `Set`, you have to choose), you can write a corresponding method by simply copying the loop from `AbstractList` (or `AbstractSet`).

---

In case you care about repeated elements, but not about repetitions, you may be able to sort of copy as amit proposed. However, sorting needs `Comparable` elements or a `Comparator`, so it needn't apply. A very trivial solution is Guava's [Multiset](https://guava-libraries.googlecode.com/svn/tags/release02/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/Multiset.html).

However, things like the one you're asking for rarely occur in a good design. Usually it's better to

- drop the setters
- add a setter-like method copying the content into a desired concrete collection

Comment: I disagree. This is not an alternative definition of equals for the set, it is an alternative definition of equals for HIS CLASS.

Comment: @amit: Yes, that's true and that's why updated my answer. However, doing this may lead to needless confusion.